# Linear fit of maximums of a oscillating function

Tags: python, python-3.x, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a linear fit of some oscillating data i have. For this i am using python 3 for convenience.

The data looks as follow

[image]

I made this data using the following expression `exp(-a*x)*abs(cos(b*x))`. In reality, my real experimental data is not as pretty or well behaved, but shows the same behaviour of an exponential decreases and an oscillation.

My objective is to find the `a` parameter. Either by doing an exponential fit of the maximums of each oscillation, or by doing a linear fit of the maximums of the log of my data.

How can i selectively chose the maximums of the oscillations if i don't know the oscillation period?

I tried to find a way to search for the minimums so i can create an interval and then finding the maximum between that interval. However finding the minimum or the maximum is the same task.

Comment: Visually, can you tell me the value of the derivative when you reach a "maximum" or a "minimum"?  :)

Comment: at each minimums there is no derivative. Since it is a discontinuity because is an absolute value, or infinity since is the derivative at a `v`-shape point. But at each maximums the derivative is zero. (Is that your question?)

Comment: I have to say, that my experimental data sometimes doesn't have enough points to calculate a 'good' derivative. But most of the times it could work (maybe?)

Comment: Well, you got my point. You approximate the position of your maximums. Use the median, not the mean. ;)